# C# Track objects that are removed by Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I've been programming a WPF UI that connects to a TCP Server and receives a constant networkStream. Depending on what I receive, I interpret the data and do different things.

My problem now is that it seems like the Handling of the networkStream causes a lot of Garbage Collections as seen in the Screenshot. These Collections cause a huge CPU Load, which I would like to prevent at all.

So my question is if there is a possibility to see, which objects the Garbage Collector actually removes so that I can optimize my code.
I am looking for a way either via code or directly viewable inside Visual Studio 2022.

I try to "recycle" most of my variables and objects so I am unsure where to start searching..

[image: Screenshot of GC at Runtime]

Comment: Using _Performance Monitor_ (aka _Perfmon_) with the .NET Memory Counters can give you a lot of info. You need to understand how the GC works, e.g., that Gen0 collections are cheap and expected, but Gen2 are very expensive. Also, large objects (greater than 85 kb) can spin off Gen2 collections. If you are doing the same thing over and over with instances of the same class, consider creating a bucket of instances and managing your allocation and reclamation of those instances yourself. Have you actually measured that GC is causing a high CPU load?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what a memory profiler is for.

The visual studio memory profiler have an [allocation view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/dotnet-alloc-tool?view=vs-2022) you should be able to use. Figuring out what *exactly* what causes the high allocation rate can be a bit more work.

As a general rule you want to avoid short lived allocations of large objects, often memory streams, since these tend to fragment the Large Object Pool, and require more frequent gen 2 collections. The typical workaround is to use pooled memory. Some APIs support `Span<T>` that may make this easier to do.

You might also want to use a performance profiler to measure the amount of *time* spent at garbage collection. Many collections does not necessarily mean any problem. For a application with a user interface the maximum blocking time may be more relevant, since that can lead to noticeable stutter in the application.